# Turn off trace globally

Tags: asp.net

I am receiving an error that ends with:

> Trace requires that...

How can we turn off trace for the whole web application? Here is the full error message:

> Multiple controls with the same ID 'x$x$xxxYyyyyZzzzzzzz$ctl00$ctl01' were found. Trace requires that controls have unique IDs.

Comment: This would be a much better Q&A if there were ways to solve the problem instead of turning off trace.  [There doesnt appear to be many answers](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23+%22Trace+requires+that+controls+have+unique%22+site:%3Dstackoverflow.com) for this problem.

Comment: For example.... are you using [master pages](http://forums.asp.net/t/1001681.aspx?Multiple+controls+with+the+same+ID+aspnetForm+were+found+Trace+requires+that+controls+have+unique+IDs+)?

Answer (score 0):

We only need to disable tracing if it was enabled in the first place.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I.e. change the above to `enabled="false"` and we're done.

See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973%28v=vs.140%29.aspx